# Find distance from points along lines

Tags: qgis, point, distance, buffer, linear-referencing

I have two layers, one is a point layer of schools and another is a polyline layer of streets. **The end goal is to create a buffer along the lines that is 20 feet from the centerline that goes 1 mile in distance from the school/point layer**.

Perhaps I am not phrasing this question correctly so if it is already answered somewhere else, I would gladly accept that.

I am using QGIS, which I am brand new to using. I have several years experience with ArcGIS (student license expired since graduation).

Would the plugin for [QChainage](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qchainage/) accomplish this? Has anyone used this plugin?

If I had access to ArcGIS, it looks like this would be a Linear Referencing question. Would Locate Features Along Route be able to solve this problem?

Edit: [Measuring the distance between lines and points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34033/measuring-the-distance-between-lines-and-points-in-qgis) looks like it's finding the distance from a point to a line which is **not** what I am asking. I am asking to find the distance *along* a line from a point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring the distance between lines and points in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34033/measuring-the-distance-between-lines-and-points-in-qgis)

Comment: This looks like it's finding the distance from a point to a line which is **not** what I am asking. I am asking to find the distance *along* a line from a point.

Comment: In that case, this post might help you: [QGIS calculate distance of point along a line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25337/qgis-calculate-distance-of-point-along-a-line). If it still doesn't help, please consider adding an image to your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Buffer the schools by 1 mile. Use those buffers to select the roads/lines within the buffers (might have to extract the data). Now buffer the lines by 20 ft.

Comment: @mkennedy the distance will be different, particularly if the road turns or going on to a new road.

Comment: @giscard78 I thought of that. Any road that turns will hit 1 mile in distance before a radial road will, so you will only have "false positives" if  you just buffer 1 mile.