# Calculating Euclidean distance in QGIS 2.18.27

Tags: qgis

I want to calculate Euclidean distance of animals trails from roads. Is this possible as both layers or vectors? Or is there another way to calculate distance my animal trail network is from a road?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measuring the distance between lines and points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34033/measuring-the-distance-between-lines-and-points-in-qgis) - v.distance works between lines, too.

Comment: If the linked solution doesn't answer your question, you can [edit] your question with an explanation of why not, and it will automatically be nominated for re-opening.